# MySQL select complementary pairs on particular values

Tags: mysql

I have the following table (MySQL):

[image]

I need to select the complementary pairs of accessions having different properties grouped by folder. In other words I do not want to group accessions having same property values for one folder.

As a final result I need to get:

[image]

I came up with something like that, but I am getting doubled results (strait and reversed pairs).

```
select    distinct a.accession, a.folder, b.accession, b.folder
from      main a 
     join main b on a.accession!= b.accession AND a.folder= b.folder
where    a.property not in (select c.property from main c where c.accession = b.accession)
and      b.property not in (select c.property from main c where c.accession = a.accession)
group by a.accession, a.folder, b.accession;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your JOIN statement as follows:

```
     join main b on a.accession < b.accession AND a.folder= b.folder
```

This should include `a.accession` = "Z1" and `b.accession` = "Z2", but exclude `a.accession` = "Z2" and `b.accession` = "Z1".